# strncpy append 1 extra(weird or random)char

Tags: c, substring, concatenation, strncpy

I wrote a simple c program that only take the first two characters of one word and take the last three characters of the second word. I use strncpy to only copy the first 2 letter of name1 to name, and concatenate with the last three characters from name2.

However, when I run it. output will somehow like

```
Ediacy //correct

acy  //wrong

Ed?
acy  //wrong

Edk
   acy //wrong

Edv
   acy //wrong

// code sample
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void)
{
    char name[100];

    char name1[] = "Edison";
    char *name2 = "Tracy";

    strncpy(name, name1, 2); // instead of get Ed, it tried to append one extra char behind it.
    strcat(name, name2+2);

    printf("%s\n", name);

    return 0; 
}
```

I will really appreciate if anyone help me to figure it out why it acts like this and how I can correct it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`strncpy` doesn't add a nul-terminator if the size is too small.

Try this:

```
strncpy(name, name1, 2);
name[2] = '\0';
```

Comment: +1 And it *always* writes `N` chars, where N is the third parameter. If the source string is smaller than N-chars, it will tail-fill to N with null-chars. (Always, of course, provided the implementation is standard-compliant).

Comment: Remember that the same rule is also valid for fgets() and similar functions.

Comment: @none Which rule? `fgets(buffer, size, stream)` always 0-terminates `buffer`, and reads fewer than `size - 1` characters from `stream` if it encounters a `'\n'` or end of input before.

Comment: Read your answer and tried it. You're right. I'm surprised for that because my reference manual exactly said that fgets() doesn't put a '\0' character on each string.

Sorry for my mistake, Pubby.